# Install ssh2 with PHP7.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Tags: php, wordpress, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I have been trying to install libssh2 on my Ubuntu server without any success. I recently had to upgrade to PHP7.1 from PHP5 because of Wordpress and Stripe requiring a more recent version of PHP.

The method my Wordpress websites update themes and plugins use SSH with the [method described here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu). Problem is I get messages such as:

```
Update Failed: Unable to locate WordPress content directory (wp-content).
```

or

```
Updating...
```

However it will sometimes say it's updating continuously.

Some help getting my Ubuntu server correctly setup for SSH2 on PHP7.1 so my Wordpress website can update using the config in my config file:

```
define('FTP_PUBKEY','/home/xxxx/wp_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY','/home/xxxx/wp_rsa');
define('FTP_USER','xxxx');
define('FTP_PASS','');
define('FTP_HOST','127.0.0.1:22');
```

would be awesome :)

Update...

I have tried installing SSH2 using the [method described here](https://medium.com/php-7-tutorial/solution-how-to-compile-php7-with-ssh2-f23de4e9c319), but no dice.

Comment: Wordpress *recommends* PHP 7, but works on PHP as old as 5.2.4. Stripe appears to work on PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, but I am already running PHP7.1 now. Running `php -m` tells me that `ssh2` is "there". Not sure if that means its running. Back onto Stripe an error message came up on the latest update saying it won't work without PHP7.